# NServiceBus Send() vs SendLocal() and exceptions

Tags: nservicebus

We are implementing a saga that calls out to other services with NServiceBus. I'm not quite clear about how NServiceBus deals with exceptions inside a saga.

Inside the saga we have a handler, and that handler calls an external service that should only be called once the original message handler completes succesfully. Is it okay to do:

```
public void Handle(IFooMessage message) 
{
    var message = Bus.CreateInstance<ExternalService.IBarMessage>();
    Bus.Send(message);

    // something bad happens here, exception is thrown
}
```

or will the message be sent to ExternalService multiple times? Someone here has suggested changing it to:

```
// handler in the saga
public void Handle(IFooMessage message) 
{
    // Do something
    var message = Bus.CreateInstance<ISendBarMessage>();
    Bus.SendLocal(message);

    // something bad happens, exception is thrown
}

// a service-level handler
public void Handle(ISendBarMessage message) 
{
    var message = Bus.CreateInstance<ExternalService.IBarMessage>();
    Bus.Send(message);
}
```

I've done an experiment and from what I can tell the first method seems fine, but I can't find any documentation other than http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/errors/ which says:

> When an exception bubbles through to the NServiceBus infrastructure, it rolls back the transaction on a transactional endpoint, causing the message to be returned to the queue, and **any messages that user code tried to send or publish to be undone as well**.

Any help to clarify this point would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you're doing messaging from your saga and not doing any web service calls, then you're safe - no need to do SendLocal.